# EclipseLink (JPA) table-based multitenancy with JTA, how?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant, jta

Our application project is an OSGI bundle using JPA with EclipseLink and JTA, and needs single-table multi-tenancy, where tenant ID comes from a REST request. From what I've read and tried, it almost seems that is impossible:

1. Since tenant ID changes depending on the request, each request with a new tenant ID needs to manually create a new `PersistenceContext` (`EntityManager`) with the appropriate property.
2. But persistence contexts can't be manually created when using JTA (`@PersistenceUnit` does not get injected and `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` does not work), according to http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html.

Am I missing something? Or is this literally impossible to do?

Comment: The doc you state is TomEE specific - most other containers allow you to get the EntityManagerFactory in a JTA environment with EntityManagers participating in the JTA transaction. Is TomEE disallowing the @PersistenceUnit with transaction-type="JTA" ?

Comment: I'm not sure wether it's EE or not, we're using ServiceMix as the platform (Apache Karaf OSGI) and EclipseLink as the JPA implementation for persistence. Blueprint is the dependency manager tying it all together.

Comment: So try adding a @PersistenceUnit to get an EMF and obtain the EntityManager from it yourself. Calling em.flush somewhere in your transactional methods should throw an exception right away if it isn't hooked into JTA correctly. You may have to call em.joinTransaction.

Comment: `@PersistenceUnit` annotated field does not get injected (is always `null`) when using JTA.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multitenant/discriminator properties in the entity manager for a request. But it is not safe for multi-threading and lazy initialization.

I tried our [CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) that supports single-table multitenancy. For each tenant, a new EntityManager should be used. That is, an EntityManager should not be shared to access data for multiple tenants. This is also true for EclipseLink.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of [CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com), a light weight JPA implementation for Java and Android.